# Cannot install/enable shell extension "Vitals"

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I am new to Ubuntu/Linux. I am trying to install the shell extension `Vitals` ([here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1460/vitals/)). I have run

```
apt install gir1.2-gtop-2.0 lm-sensors
```

as mentioned in its [github](https://github.com/corecoding/Vitals) page. According to the installation instruction, I had to restart Gnome (I rebooted) and use `gnome-tweak-tools` to enable the extension. But I don't see it in tweak tools extension list. Here are the extensions I can see in tweak-tools:
[tweak-tools view of extensions 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZAAs.png)
[tweak-tools view of extensions 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JJZ2.png).

What am I missing?

`~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` doesn't exist for me. The result for `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` as follows:

```
total 68
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root 4096 Jul 30 17:02 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Jul 30 10:03 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 30 17:02 apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 30 17:02 auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 23 21:43 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 30 17:02 drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 30 17:02 horizontal-workspaces@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 30 17:02 launch-new-instance@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 30 17:02 native-window-placement@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 30 17:02 places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 30 17:02 screenshot-window-sizer@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Apr 23 13:35 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Jul 23 21:43 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 30 17:02 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 30 17:02 window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 30 17:02 windowsNavigator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 30 17:02 workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

My GNOME Shell version is 3.36.3.

I have also downloaded a zip file for shell version 3.36 and extension version 33. But I don't know what to do with it.

Output of `ls` where the .zip file has been downloaded:

```
VitalsCoreCoding.com.v33.shell-extension.zip
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments...

To install/enable the `Vitals` GNOME Shell extension:

In `terminal` do the following...

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gir1.2-gtop-2.0 lm-sensors
```

Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and follow the instructions to enable managing your GNOME Shell extensions. You may have to register and login at https://extensions.gnome.org/.

Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1460/vitals/ and click the ON switch to install Vitals.

Click the BLUE settings icon to adjust your Vitals preferences.